# Show all Currently Running Jobs for all Projects in Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

On my Rundeck there are multiple projects and jobs under these projects are triggered by schedule and some run for a a few minutes to an hour.

I want to restart the rundeck server to apply some configuration changes without having to affect these jobs so I want to know if there are any currently running jobs from each projects.

I know I can manually go through each project and check each running job but i want to see all of it at once.

Is this possible?

Comment: Still dont have that feature with the latest build. Try posting a feature request at https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues

Answer (score 1):

In case it's still relevant:

You can either query the DB directly: H2/internal or external wherever you've put it.

Or using the API (simply list all projects and query for each one the running jobs.

Comment: Thanks. checked as you suggested. I was hoping there was a UI solution though

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using the CLI with something like:

```
for i in $(rd projects list | grep -v ^#); do
  rd executions list -p $i;
done
```